# Visual Studio 2012 Windows Form application

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I am working on Windows Form application on Visual Studio 2012. I have 2 forms.

`Add_Item_to_DB1`
         `Add_Item_to_DB2`
 Both of these forms call a third form called `SUBMIT`. Now, based on where this form is being called from, it has to submit information to a different database. Everything else in the `SUBMIT` form is EXACTLY the same except, data is inserted to a different database.

Is there a way to find out where the form is being called from? Kinda new to Form applications.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the SUBMIT form with the `ShowDialog()` method you will be able to determine the form that opened the SUBMIT form via the `Owner` property. For example:

```
public partial class Add_Owner_To_Db_1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var submitForm = new SUBMIT();

        submitForm.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}

public partial class SUBMIT : Form
{
    private void SUBMIT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //label1.Text will equal "Add_Owner_To_Db_1"
        label1.Text = this.Owner.Text;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can expose a public property on your SUBMIT form that can be populated from the parent form. For example:

```
public partial class Add_Owner_To_Db_1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var submitForm = new SUBMIT();

        submitForm.ParentName = "Add_Owner_To_Db_1";

        submitForm.Show();
    }
}

public partial class SUBMIT : Form
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }

    private void SUBMIT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //label1.Text will equal "Add_Owner_To_Db_1"
        label1.Text = ParentName;
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: If I want to display a messagebox with the owner, do I just do `messageBox.show(this.Owner.ToString())`? It keeps throwing an error about how the Object reference is not set to an instance of the object.

Comment: Firstly, make sure you are using MessageBox.Show() rather than messageBox.show() (notice the capitalisation). Secondly, if you are wanting to use the Owner property make sure you are loading the form using ShowDialog().

Comment: Oh yes, the typo was just here. Intellisense got me covered on that. Thank you, again. You were helpful.